# Pull DateTime field using alternate timezone?

Tags: datetime, timezone

I have a question regarding populating models, in that I have a `DateTime` field in my model that I'm pulling / populating from the database. The `DateTime` value does not include the timezone it was set to when it was stored, its stored in UTC.

I have the original timezone value (Not the same as the CRAFT timezone but the users timezone that actually created the entry) stored in the model attributes as well.

Is there a way I can extend the model so that when the data is populated I can force the correct timezone on the `DateTime` fields?

I'm pretty sure that Craft is going to convert them to the timezone craft is set to when it pulls it into the model, but I dont want that in this case. I want it set to the TZ stored in the "timeZone" column/attribute...

Example:

Craft Timezone is America/Chicago

The user's timezone is America/New_York

The user selects a date and time and the controller creates the DateTime object with the user's selection, specifying the timezone America/New_Yrok, then tells the model to save, so it stores it in the database.

The Database DateTime value is now stored in UTC.

When I fetch this data and populate a model with it and reference the DateTime object, its going to be in Amercia/Chicago right? since that's what the craft system is set to, right?

So what is the best way to set up the model so it automatically knows to use `$this->getAttribute('timeZone')` as the timezone for that field rather than the Craft system setting?

EDIT:

This is what I ended up doing that appears to work. I added this to my model:

```
public static function populateModel($values) {
    $model = PARENT::populateModel($values);

    /** @var $startTime DateTime */
    $startTime = $model->getAttribute('startTime');
    if($startTime) {
        $startTime->setTimezone($model->timeZone);
        $model->setAttribute('startTime', $startTime);
    }
    /** @var $endTime DateTime|null */
    $endTime = $model->getAttribute('endTime');
    if($endTime) {
        $endTime->setTimezone($model->timeZone);
        $model->setAttribute('endTime', $endTime);
    }

    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100% untested, but something like this should work:

1. Have your model override BaseModel's [populateModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#populateModel-detail).
2. Find the DateTime field you're interested in and get its value.
3. Create a new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and pass in the value from the `timeZone` attribute.
4. Set the new DateTime object back on the original DateTime field.
5. Call `parent::populateModel($values)`.